# How can i call the other class's function into the class?

Tags: python, class, error-handling

I wrote this code but it's giving me an error whenever I'm trying to press 3 so it's calling the function but after input value, it's giving me an error please someone help me.

I edit the code and I have removed the jerk.  please check now

```
class Library:
    def show(self):
        self.Book_list=["English","Python","Urdu"]
        print(f"Hellow! You can see the available books Below:\n")
        print("\n".join(map(str,self.Book_list)))
    def __init__(self):
        self.BookName=input("\nEnter The Book Name").capitalize()
        return self.BookName
    def Remove(self):
        if self.BookName in self.Book_list:
            self.Book_list.remove(self.BookName)
            print("You have Got this Book Successfully! Please return the book before 30 Days. ThankYou!")  
        else:
            print("Book not Available! Please Request later!")
    def append(self):
        if self.BookName not in self.Book_list:
            self.Book_list.append(self.BookName)
            print("Hi Thanks for Returning the Book")
        else:
            print("Hi Thanks for Returning the Book")      
class student:
    def Show_Books(self):return Library.show(self)
    def Borrow(self):return Library.show(self),Library.__init__(self),Library.Remove(self)
    def Return(self):return Library.__init__(self),Library.append(self)
stu=student()
while(True):
    stu=student()
    Msg=("\n\n\n====================== Hi Welcome To The SSUET Library ======================\n\nPlease Select The Option Below:\n\n Press '1' To See The Book's List. \n Press '2' For Borrow.\n Press '3' To Return The Book\n Press 'Q' for Quit")
    print(Msg)
    slc=int(input("Press"))  
    if slc==1:stu.Show_Books()
    elif slc==2:stu.Borrow()
    elif slc==3:stu.Return()
    elif slc==4:
        print("Quit")
        break   

Error::::::::::::
if self.BookName not in self.Book_list:
AttributeError: 'student' object has no attribute 'Book_list
```

Comment: What's with all the `self.y` junk in `student`?  It serves no purpose.  It's just storing `None` over and over again, since that's what all the `Library` methods return.

Comment: Please show the error also

Comment: When run your code on my local, I got this error:
`
   if self.BookName not in self.Book_list:
AttributeError: 'student' object has no attribute 'Book_list'
`

you replace self of Library with self (student object), that is why the error appeared.

Comment: @HenroSutrisnoTanjungTraceback Hellow This error coming out when I'm returning the book and input the name (most recent call last):
  File "a:\My python course\zproject3\project3.py", line 47, in <module>
    stu.Return()
  File "a:\My python course\zproject3\project3.py", line 27, in Return
    self.y=Library.append(self)
  File "a:\My python course\zproject3\project3.py", line 19, in append
    if self.BookName not in self.Book_list:
AttributeError: 'student' object has no attribute 'Book_list'